# Tensorflow not getting installed: Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install tensorflow in Anaconda prompt using the command. I am getting the error below.

```
 python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

**Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored**

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is some problem with the Python 3 cache which is causing it to download data it should already be able to retrieve from its cache. My guess would be that the decoding of data from Python 2's cache is failing which is giving you this error message. Try clearing the cache and see if anything changes.